# Dimension of a complex vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, ideals

> We have the polynomial $$f=x^4+x^2y^2+y^3-x^3\in\mathbb{C}[x,y].$$ Consider the ideal $I=\langle f,\frac{df}{dx},\frac{df}{dy}\rangle$. I am trying to compute the dimension of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/I$ as a complex vector space.

I don't really know where to start, my first idea would be to calculate $\dim(\mathbb{C}[x,y])-\dim(I)$, but the first one is infinite. Any hints on how should I approach?

Comment: Well, both of those vector spaces are infinite dimensional, so subtracting won't really make sense. I'd start out by calculating $I$ and coming up with as simple a generating set for it as I could. I might also note that $1,x,y,x2,xy,y^2,x^3,...$ forms a basis for $\mathbb [x,y]$. Maybe the images of the elements of some subset of that list form a basis for the quotient.

Comment: Do you know what a Gröbner basis is?  [They can be used to compute the dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis#Dimension.2C_degree_and_Hilbert_series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macaulay2 shows that $x^2,y^2$ is a Gröbner basis for $I$, so $$\dim_{\mathbb C}\mathbb C[x,y]/I=\dim_{\mathbb C}\mathbb C[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)=4.$$

Comment: Let's see if I got it right, so all the monomials not contained in $I$ form a basis of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/I$, and those are $1,x,y$ and $xy$ so the dimension is 4 as a complex vector space. I also need to prove that $x^5\equiv y^5$ (mod $I$), would be as easy as saying that $x^5-y^5=x^3x^2-y^3y^2\in I$?

Comment: @Jorge You are right.